# Spring Boot Application which triggers another App with CLI

Tags: python, spring, rest, docker, containers

I am currently developing a Spring Boot Application which triggers a Python program via CLI. I've used Processbuilder to do that and it's been working ok so far.

Now I'm trying to get the Spring Boot Application and the Python program in a Docker container. Since I'm new to Docker I don't know the best way to do this. I've tried using COPY to copy the whole folder to create an image but for some reason the folder pythonapp in the Container is always empty.

Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this?

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jdk-slim
EXPOSE 8080
ADD springbootapp-0.0.1.jar app.jar 
COPY . /root/pythonapp
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python \
python-gi \
gir1.2-gtk-3.0
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the idea of docker is that 1 container does 1 thing and 1 thing good. So it mostly is not a good idea to put two things in 1 docker container. Think about two containers :-)

Other than that it might be a good idea to add files separately or as a tar/zip file and extract it in the image.

Comment: How do I trigger the python app on another container? Is there a way to access the CLI with rest? Since I'm using Processbuilder and a path to do this I have no idea how I should do that with two containers.

Comment: You are right this might then not be what you need. You might ask the question why you need to run a python program from within your java application. That might be bad design, but that is not the subject of the question here. In this case you do want to have it in one container probably.